Docker - Laravel API return 404 Not Found
I dockerized a laravel project with apache and mysql using the following configuration :
Dockerfile :
FROM php:8.2-apache
 WORKDIR /var/www/html
# Mod Rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite
# Linux Library
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev
# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
# copy laravel project
COPY ./application /var/www/html
# grant permission
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

docker-compose.yml :
version: '3'

services:

  laravel-docker:
    container_name: laravel-docker
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 9000:80
  
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nawarni
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

In docker i ran this command docker-compose up -d --build
Inside the laravel-docker container i typed these commands :
composer install
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
php artisan serve
At this point everything worked well and my DB is created and the server is running
But then when i test my APIs in Postman i get 404 Not Found
